# CruiseControl.net statistics tutorial

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, dashboard

The statistics module of CC.Net is very interesting. But the documentation about it is very poor. I did some internet research to figure out how to include a new counter (ex: LOC, compiler warnings, etc.) or other graphics to show but found nothing structured. Does anyone know where I could find a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://igorbrejc.net/development/cruisecontrolnet/keeping-track-of-code-comment-warnings-in-your-ccnet-builds